# Nuxt + Vuetify using Content Security Policy (CSP) header inline styling

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuetify.js, content-security-policy

For my company I need to update our Nuxt + Vuetify application to make use of a Content Security Policy (CSP) header.
`'unsafe-inline'` is not allowed for `'default-src'`. The problem we are currently facing is that Vuetify adds style attributes at runtime to the DOM elements.

So for example:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-system-bar app>
    <v-container>Content</v-container>
  </v-system-bar>
</div>
```

Results in:

```
<div class="v-system-bar v-system-bar--fixed theme--light" style="height: 24px;">
    <div class="container">Content</div>
</div>
```

The CSP header does not allow the `style="height: 24px"`. This gives me the following error:

`Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src https://unpkg.com/ 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-gGKtWVlwtb9dj1Sa7K4ybKpqUOE61nkachaCJ1LfmFY='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.`

This problem also occurs for other vuetify components, the `v-system-bar` is just an example. I know that adding a nonce for `<style>` elements is possible, but not for `style` attributes. Is there a way to solve this problem, besides setting the header to `unsafe-inline`? I want to keep using Vuetify together with the CSP header.

Here is a codepen link: https://codepen.io/erikeuserr/pen/WNpbOwx.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructions like `style="height: 24px"` appear in the code as result of *vue.js* (not *vuetify.js*) script work. A *vue.js* uses a `el.setAttribute()` func to set *style=* property. The `el.setAttribute('style', ...)` is counted by CSP as unsafe therefore *vue.js* is not CSP-compatible.

But `el.style.property = '...'` is safe, so in order to make *vue.js* a CSP compatible, it need to replace all `el.setAttribute('style', 'background-color:#e2e2e2; height: 24px; display:inline;')` by the according sets of:

```
el.style.backgroundColor = '#e2e2e2';
el.style.height = '24px';
el.style.display = 'inline';
```

1. There is a [rough hack](https://csplite.com/csp/test343/) to do this - globally redefine `setAttribute()` when it's called with a `'style'` argument.
2. Before output the page into browser, you can catch and replace all `style='...'` by `data-style='...'` in the html code, and then use script like:

   `styleList = document.querySelectorAll("[data-style]");`
   `styleList.forEach( function(style) {`
     `// convert a 'background-color:#e2e2e2; height: 24px; display:inline;' strings`
     `// to the set of 'el.style.backgroundColor = '#e2e2e2'; ... el.style.display = 'inline';'<br>`  });`

Yes, these are patches, but understanding the essence of the problem, you may be able to find a more elegant solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! How can I catch and replace all `style='...'` attributes using Vue, is there something like a hook available to catch the HTML before it outputs to the browser?

Comment: It's possible if you use [VueJS Server-Side Rendering](https://ssr.vuejs.org/#what-is-server-side-rendering-ssr). For example you can use [renderer.renderToString(app)](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/bundle-renderer.html#enter-bundlerenderer) to catch HTML: `const html = await renderer.renderToString(app);`

Comment: But in that case you don't have access to things like `document` right? I tried this in a Nuxt module that contains a `render:route` Nuxt hook. That one was able to catch the HTML aswell. However I was not able to call things like `document.querySelectorAll("[data-style]");` because I was SSR context, which makes things like `document` or `window` unavailable. I guess that using VueJS Server Side Rendering has the same problem?

Comment: Yes, the `document` property is available only in browser. At server side you can use something like regular expressions.